# How to implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'?

Tags: c#, types, return

I am new to C# but in the learning process. I am trying to get a list of Departments to show in a listbox on a form. The datamodel is fine. The interface is well declared. But just one line in the click event of my button is refusing to compile.

I have this error in my button click event:

> Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataModel.Department>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<PayrollDAL.DepartmentRepository>'

This is my interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class

{
    List<T> GetAll();
    bool Add(T employee);
    T GetById(int id);
    bool Update(T employee);
    bool Delete(int id);
}
```

This is my implementation

```
public class DepartmentRepository : IRepository<Department>
{

    public bool Add(Department department)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<Department> GetAll()
    {
        string sql = "select * from Department";

        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("boa")))
        {
            var output = connection.Query<Department>(sql).ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }

    public Department GetById(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Update(Department department)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is my click event with the offending line.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DepartmentRepository dept = new DepartmentRepository();
        depts = dept.GetAll(); // offending line
        UpdateBinding();

    }
```

I expect to get a list to populate my listbox with. But it cannot compile due to the error message above.

How should I convert my departments generic list to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'can resolve it, please?

Comment: what is the type of the `depts` variable?

Comment: Of course you cannot directly (implicitly or explicitly) convert a `List<DataModel.Department>` to a `List<PayrollDAL.DepartmentRepository>`. Being able to do so would be paradoxical. The question here is rather: What is your motivation of wanting to treat a `List<DataModel.Department>` as if it were a `List<PayrollDAL.DepartmentRepository>`?

Comment: @Tor List<DepartmentRepository> depts = new List<DepartmentRepository>();

Comment: @elgonzo - Since I am learning C# I am unable at this point to see where problem is. Variable depts is declared in the form as List<DepartmentRepository> depts = new List<DepartmentRepository>(); So I dont know why dept.GetAll() should not work. I will appreciate any help here.

Comment: Look at the return type of your `GetAll()` method, and compare it with the type of your `depts` variable. Then look at the error message. Then look at my previous comment again. Your assumption kinda seems to be equivalent to believing a list of houses (List<House>) is the same as a list of persons (List<Person>), which would be just silly. Just because houses can contain people does not mean a list of houses is a list of persons. A list of houses is a list of buildings, but it is not a list of persons or list of pet animals living in those houses.

Comment: @elgonzo - Thanks a lot. You have cleared some misunderstanding I had. The error has cleared.